# Mysql partition error?

Tags: mysql, range, database-partitioning

I have a kinda table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user VARCHAR(30),
    time VARCHAR(30),
    status VARCHAR(30),
    origin VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
PARTITION BY RANGE(id) (
    PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (500000),
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (1000000),
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (1500000),
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2000000),
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2500000)             
)
```

I have Three questions:

1) I have here an #1064 error;

2) How can i set split test.user as alphabetic range in partition;

3) How can i check that the partition was successful;

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot RANGE partition on char/varchar/text.

What you can do is add a int column called ascii_value. Then create a before insert/update trigger which will update the ascii_value column with the the ASCII value of the first letter in the string.

Now you can partition the table on ascii_value column.

If you want to go further and create partitions based on combination of first few letters like
aa
ab
ac
ad

Then you can do this:

`ascii_value = ascii_value_of_first_letter<<8 + ascii_value_of_second_letter`

for three letters:

`ascii_value = ascii_value_of_first_letter<<16 + ascii_value_of_second_letter<<8 +  ascii_value_of_third_letter`

Like you can see, the limitation to this scheme is the number of bits available in the `ascii_value` field. But that won't be a problem since you would exhaust the number of permissible partitions before you exhaust the bits in `ascii_value` field.

This is ok if you are HASH partitioning. For range partitiong, you better do something like this

`ascii_value = (ascii_value_of_first_letter_in_uppercase - 65)*26 + ascii_value_of_second_letter_in_uppercase -65`

This will give a continuous range of values.

While  querying, you will have to apply the same logic on the string you are trying to search. Add a condition in where clause which filters the results based on `ascii_value` field. This will prune the unnecessary partitions.

Use `EXPLAIN PARTITIONS` to see if partitions are being pruned.

PS: You will have to add `ascii_value` to the Primary Key.

Hope this helps :)